# Resolve Injecting indirect service with lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, lazy-loading

I would like some advice on resolving dependency inject in the context of 'indirect inject'. consider the example below.

Consider I have three interfaces, namely: `IAdminService`, `IEmailService`, and `IBillService`. Each has a single implementation type, i.e. `AdminService`, `EmailService`, and `BillService`.

here is an example of `IAdminService` with its implementing type.

```cs
public interface IAdminService 
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class AdminService : IAdminService 
{
    IServiceA A { get; }

    public AdminService (IServiceA A)
    {
        this.A = A;
    }

    public void DoSomething(){
    {
        A.QuerySomething();
    }
}
```

On top of that I have an `IServiceManagement` abstraction, that makes use of lazy loading. see below.

```cs
public interface IServiceManagement
{
    IAdminService AdminService{ get;  }
    IEmailService IEmailService{ get; }
    IBillService BillService { get; }
}

public sealed class ServiceManagement : IServiceManagement
{
    private readonly Lazy<IAdminService> _adminService;
    private readonly Lazy<IEmailService> _emailService;
    private readonly Lazy<IBillService> _billService;

    public ServiceManagement (
        IServiceA ServiceA,
        IServiceB ServiceB,
        IserviceC serviceC,
        ...)
    {
        _adminService = new Lazy<IAdminService>(() => new AdminService(ServiceA));
        _emailService = new Lazy<IEmailService>(() => new EmailService(...));
        _billService = new Lazy<IBillService>(() => new BillService(...));
    }

    public IAdminService AdminService => _adminService.Value;
    public IEmailService EmailService => _emailService.Value;
    public IBillService BillService => _billService.Value;
}
```

Service are registered as a scoped service (Web API), see extension method below below.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection RegisterLogicServices(
    this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IServiceManagement, ServiceManagement>();

    //generic services like UnitOfWork for E.F. Core etc.
    services.AddScoped<IServiceA , ServiceA>();
    services.AddScoped<IServiceB , ServiceB>();
    services.AddScoped<IServiceC , ServiceC>();

    return services;
}
```

For example, to make use of `IServiceManagement` at the controller level, I inject `IServiceManagement` as constructor argument, allowing me to access all publicly exposed methods of the service, as follows:

```cs
public DoSomethingController(IServiceManagement manager)
{
  _manager = manager
}

public IActionResult ExecuteSomething()
{
    _manager.AdminService.DoSomething();

    return Ok();
}
```

Everything works perfectly at this point.

What I'm wondering, however, is whether it is possible to have scope of `IServiceManagement` in `IAdminService`, so i would like to execute something in `IEmailService` in `IAdminService` via `IServiceManagement`.

A way I can think of doing this is by using `IServiceProvider`, and passing in `provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceManagement>()` as a property of the constructor, like below

```cs
public ServiceManagement (
    IServiceA ServiceA,
    IServiceB ServiceB,
    IserviceC serviceC,
    IServiceProvider provider,
    ...)
{
    _adminService = new Lazy<IAdminService>(
        () => new AdminService(
            ServiceA,
            provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceManagement>()));
    _emailService = new Lazy<IEmailService>(() => new EmailService(...));
    _billService= new Lazy<IBillService>(() => new BillService(...));
}
```

I'd do that for all of the services, cause there might be a scenario where `IAdminService` calls a method in `IEmailService`, and that same method in `IEmailService` might call a method in `IBillService`, etc.

What i would like to know, is making use of `IServiceProvider` for this use case a valid one, for example,

- is it valid in the context of Dependency Injection?
- would I run into issues when accessing anything from `IServiceProvider`?
- would this cause performance degradation if the call tree is to big (or because its scoped it should be fine)?
- etc.

And lets take the extreme case and say I inject `IServiceManagment` into a Background Service, would that cause any issues.

If you have another solution that solves my worries, please mention it, i'd like to learn as much as possible on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it valid in the context of Dependency Injection?

No, it probably isn't.

What's missing from your question is *why* exactly you require lazy loading. This is important, because in general injection constructors [should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). Having simple injection constructors makes object construction fast and diminishes the need to do lazy loading. Without lazy loading, there is no need in having the `IServiceManagement` around. This simplifies your solution and removes your current issue: the cyclic dependency.

But even when it's impossible to remove a slow loading dependency, wrapping dependencies in an `IServiceManagement` abstraction is not a proper solution. By doing this, you are leaking implementation details: the fact that a service is slow to load. Consuming dependencies shouldn't be aware of that. On top of that, by exposing all of `IServiceManagement`'s dependency, you're creating a solution where you hide the actual number of dependencies that a class uses, and making it harder to test classes, because you have to manage an `IServiceManagement` implementations in your tests as well. And in the end, `IServiceManagement` will become that one single dependency that all classes depend upon; much like the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).

Instead, the use of proxy implementations is a more elegant solution. In this case you implement, for instance, an `IAdminService` implementation that allows lazy loading the real `IAdminService` implementation. For instance:

```cs
public sealed class LazyAdminService : IAdminService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IAdminService> lazy;
    public LazyAdminService(Lazy<IAdminService> lazy) => this.lazy = lazy;

    public void DoSomething() => this.lazy.Value.DoSomething();
}
```

Assuming your using MS.DI as your DI Container, you can wire this up as follows:

```cs
services.AddScoped<AdminService>();
services.AddScoped<IAdminService>(c => new LazyAdminService(
    new Lazy<IAdminService>(() => c.GetRequiredService<AdminService>()));
```

This is more elegant, because the consumers of `IAdminService` have no notion of `AdminService` requiring lazy initialization, and they didn't require any change once `AdminService` becoming lazily initialized.

Comment: the reason why i went with `IServiceManagement`, was due to the number of interfaces that i had to account for, at the very high-end, i would say about 200 +-, and to that, I wanted to allow 'easy usage', as apposed to injecting the lazy interfaces into the implementation itself, it would easier to just add it to `IServiceManagement`, and have access to it via `_serviceManager.AdminService.?`. Do you think it's feasible to make use of the `IServiceManagement` interface reference, but use Lazy Implementation of the services. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: In an ideal situation, there should be no need for having an `IServiceManagement` interface. Especially when it has 200 interfaces. It means it is becoming a [Service Locator](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). You should strive getting out of that situation (which might not be easy if you already have 200 services that load slowly). But you should analyze the root cause why loading is slow and ensure that no I/O happens within constructors and during object composition.